# Function that returns negative number for negative x and y

Tags: functions

I need a function, $$f(x,y):\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$, that returns negative a number only if both x and y are negative. It can use only the four basic operations, so for example computing the absolute value or square root are not allowed.

I only found solution using the absolute value:
$$ -(x-|x|)*(y-|y|)$$

Is it possible with only the four basic operation (+, -, *, and/)? And if it isn't, why?

Comment: Out of curiosity,  is this restriction to those four operations something that's an arbitrary part of an assignment from an instructor,  or does it have some other context?

Comment: @Alan I don't really know why is this restriction. I was just asked for help to figure out this small part of a bigger problem.

Comment: Why don't you construct a two-branch function which will be positive if x,y are positive and negative if x,y are negative instead?

Comment: Should the return of a negative be 'if and only if' both $x$ and $y$ or negative; or, as stated in the post, 'only if both $x$ and $y$ are negative'?

Comment: Finite many or infinite many operations?

Comment: if and only if both x and y are negative.

Comment: @mvw finite many operations

Comment: It is not for some clever programming trick using overflow effects of the finite representation?

Comment: Nit: since you're defining an algebra, what you really have is *two* operations.  Subtraction is actually addition with a different element (-6 , rather than "minus" +6).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Clear, but how do You write reciprocals without division?

Comment: The reciprocal of $x$ is the element $y$ (in the same set of elements underlying your algebra) such that $x * y = 1$ -- or whatever your defined "unity" for the defined $ * $ operator is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are restricted to the four basic operations, all you can get is a rational function $f(x,y)=\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}$ where $p,q$ are polynomials in $x$ and $y$.
Since we want $f$ to be defined everywhere, $q$ must not have zeroes, so we may assume wlog. that $q(x,y)>0$ for all $x,y$. This allows us to use simply $f(x,y)=p(x,y)$, i.e. a polynomial.

If your assignment formulation really reads "only if", you can simply take $f(x,y)=0$, which never returns negative values; or try something more interesting such as $(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2-1$, which at least becomes negative for *some* points in the thord quadrant, but never in the other quadrants.

If what you want is "if and only if", however, there is no such polynomial $p$: If one plugs in an arbitrary constant $c\in\mathbb R$ for $y$, one obtains an univariate polynomial $f_c(x)=p(x,c)$ and $\deg f_c$ is the same for all $c$ with at most finitely many exceptions: If we write $p(x,y)=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x^iy^j$ (where only finitely many $a_{i,j}$ are nonzero), let $d=\max\{\,i\mid a_{i,j}\ne 0\,\}$. Then $\deg f_c\le d$ for all $c$ and the inequality is strict only if $c$ is among the fintely many solutions of $\sum_{i=d}a_{i,j}c^j=0$. 
But for the desired condition, we need that $\deg f_c$ is even for all $c\ge 0$ and odd for all $c<0$.

Comment: Pardon me, but should'nt $d=\max\{\,i\mid a_{i,j}\ne 0\,\}$ be $d=\max \left( \{\,i\mid a_{i,j}\ne 0\,\} \right)$ ?

Comment: @Nickolas That's a matter of notational convention. If $S$ is a set I usually write $\max S$, $\sup S$, $\min S$, $\inf S$ for the maximum, supremum etc. For finite cases (i.e. if $S=\{x,y,z\}$, say) I usually write $\max(x,y,z)$ instead of $\max\{x,y,z\}$, but I personally won't write $\max(\{x,y,z\})$, for instance.

Comment: You mean *third* quadrant, not fourth quadrant.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Late, but edited accordingly. While math.SE is a very active site, I should possibly subscribe to counting.SE  ;)

Comment: Couldn’t $q$ be a sum of squares? On $\mathbb R^2$, such a polynomial is never negative. I don’t think this affects your answer in any essential way…

Comment: @Lubin Yes $q$ could be a sum of squares, hence be always positive, hence can be ignored and we can simply use the numerator instead. That's what I meant.